# How to disable /files endpoints on parse-server

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard

With the newly available community version of Parse server (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) there does not seem to be a configuration option to disable the /files endpoints which allow for file upload and hosting. I would very much like to disable this feature, and Cloud Code server-side hooks are not a good option (not currently supported in parse-dashboard, among other problems). What's the best way to disable these endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little middleware works for me. Add this to your parse app config:

```
{
  "middleware": "disableFilesMiddleware",
}
```

And then for your middleware module disableFilesMiddleware.js:

```
module.exports = function( req , res , next ){

  if( req.path.substring( 0 , 12 ) === '/parse/files' ) {
    res.status(400).send({ code: 119 , message: 'files endpoints are disabled' }); 
    return;
  }

  next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Parse 5+, you can configure this in your Parse Server config to disabled all uploading:

```
fileUpload: {
  enableForPublic: false,
  enableForAnonymousUser: false,
  enableForAuthenticatedUser: false
}
```

You can read about it in the docs [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#configuring-file-upload)